# why this contract can successfully do the transfer()

Tags: solidity, erc-20, etherscan

I am reading the source code of this erc20 token:

https://etherscan.io/address/0xfdfd5db568f2ecf9b06a16116b9201b0500735b4#code

the code is like this:

```
contract VelixIDToken is ReleasableToken, BurnableToken {
    ...

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success) {
        // Call StandardToken.transfer()
        CanTransferChecked(released || transferAgents[msg.sender], msg.sender, transferAgents[msg.sender], released);
        if (released || transferAgents[msg.sender]) {
            return super.transfer(_to, _value);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    ...
}

contract ReleasableToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    ...

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success) {
        // Call StandardToken.transfer()
        CanTransferChecked(released || transferAgents[msg.sender], msg.sender, transferAgents[msg.sender], released);
        if (released || transferAgents[msg.sender]) {revert();}
        return super.transfer(_to, _value);
    }

    ...
}
```

in my understanding, the token transfer()  can never really happen, `released` is false now, so in VelixIDToken, only transferAgent can pass the check:

`if (released || transferAgents[msg.sender])`,

well in ReleasableToken, the call will revert cause :

`if (released || transferAgents[msg.sender]) {revert();}`.

but I see successful token transfer on etherscan:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfa76397fc5d1d5e155fa969f56095d4ecdad4dc90a64798ca79fa2773923fb07

so where am I wrong?

ps. I even wondered if the source code uploaded to etherscan is wrong, can this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `super.transfer` refers to the `transfer` implementation in `BurnableToken`, not the `transfer` in `ReleasableToken`. From https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#multiple-inheritance-and-linearization:

> Especially, the order in which the base classes are given in the is directive is important: You have to list the direct base contracts in the order from “most base-like” to “most derived”.